# Creating and sending an XML document in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a website where users can enter some information in tables. By clicking a button, these information should be stored in a XML document and send with AJAX.

I've already tried this to create a XML document, but it isn't working out.

```
var xmlDoc = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>';
xmlDoc.append('<customer></customer>');
```

How do I create a XML document and append further nodes and set attributes?

Comment: first you would need to create an XMLDocument object... not a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use jQuery `append` method on a string, it will throw js error.

You can try something like this.

```
var xmlDocument = $.parseXML("<root/>");
var foo = xmlDocument.createElement('foo');
foo.appendChild(document.createTextNode('bar'));
xmlDocument.documentElement.appendChild(foo);
```

Other way is to create a XML string based on the tabular information available on the page and then use `$.parseXML()` method to create XML document.

Comment: `var xmlDocument = $.parseXML("<root/>");` :-P

Comment: @Rocket - That will `parse` XML string and then we can traverse it using jQuery apis. But OP is looking to create `Xml` document.

Comment: You are not understanding me. OP wants to create a XML document from scratch. OP do not have a xml string in hand which can be parsed.

Comment: `I have a website where users can enter some information in tables. By clicking a button, these information should be stored in a XML document and send with AJAX.`

Comment: I do understand, and I was trying to help improve your answer.  I know the OP doesn't have a string to be parsed, so I am parsing the string `"<root/>"` (just like in your answer `xmlDocument.createElement('root')`).  `$.parseXML("<root/>");` will work cross-browser (as jQuery does the `createDocument`/`new ActiveXObject` for you.  I was trying to simplify/improve your answer.  [Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/bxeXT/) :-P

Comment: just interested if it's also possible to create an element with `$('newElement');`

Comment: Yes, you can create but it is won't be an `Xml` element. So you cannot use any `Xml` apis on it.

Comment: and how can I select nodes in the xml tree. Do I have to use `xmlDoxument.find('nodeName');`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `find` method to traverse through the xmlDocument.

Answer (score 3):

In the Situation where you don't really need an XML document but just an XML DOM that can be sent as string: Let jQuery handle this for you.

```
var root = $('<root>');
root.append('<customer>');
// result DOM: <root><customer></customer></root>
```

So you can set further nodes and also attributes:

```
var customer = root.children().eq(0);
$(customer).attr('id', 1);
$(customer).text('Mister Foo');
// result DOM: <root><customer id="1">Mister Foo</customer></root>
```

When really needing the XML header, just add it before the output:

```
var xmlHeader = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>'
var xmlDocumentString = xmlHeader + root.html();
// result: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><customer id="1">Mister Foo</customer>
```

Goal reached.

Comment: That returns a jQuery object, not an XMLDocument. Not sure if the difference matters here.

Comment: If the XML is to be sent via Ajax then it will be sent as a string anyway?

Comment: True, it would be sent as a string (not as an XMLDocument).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML to XML</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('ready', function() {
        $("#submitButton").on('click', function(e) {
            //This is where you construct the data you would like to save
            var fileDataToSave = $("#form1").serializeArray();
            //try catch block to catch the error if any.
            try {
                var xml = $($.parseXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><root />'));

                $(fileDataToSave).each(function(i, field) {
                    $('root', xml).append($('<' + field.name + ' />', xml).text(field.value));
                });

                //code to download xml format.
                var $downloadAnchor = $("<a/>", {
                    href: 'data:text/xml;charset=UTF-8,' + (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml.context),
                    download: "HelloWorld.xml"
                });
                $downloadAnchor.text("Click me to download XML");
                $("body").append($downloadAnchor);
                e.preventDefault();
            } catch (e) {
                document.write(e.message);
            }



        });
    });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1">
                First name:
                <input id="btn1" type="text" name="FirstName">
                <br>Last name:
                <input id="btn2" type="text" name="LastName">
                <br>
                <button id="submitButton">submit</button>
            </form>
            <p>On Click of Submit, first name and last name should be stored XML file. 
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```